# How will we get the future site into our Ubuntu theme?

Tags: discussion, top-7

What are the logistics? How to deploy?

Comment: This looks to be a dup of http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-should-our-site-be-styled

Answer (score 4):

I've mailed someone on the Canonical design team to see if they have time to help us with the branding.

EDIT: Also, by the time we're out of beta the Ubuntu font should be finished and available under a free license, we should use it on here!

Comment: Wait no longer for the Ubuntu font :)